# $G$: finitely generated abelian group of free rank $r$. compute $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

so we can write $G\cong G_1\oplus G_2$ where $G_1=\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{t_1}}\oplus...\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{t_k}}$ and $G_2=\mathbb{Z}^r$.

let $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{t_i}}$, $b_j\in\mathbb{Z}$, $s\in\mathbb{Q}$.

then a generator of $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ looks like $(a_1, ...,a_k,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes s$.

let $n=p_1^{t_1}...p_k^{t_k}$.

then $(a_1, ...,a_k,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes s=(a_1, ...,a_k,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes s\frac{n}{n}=n(a_1, ...,a_k,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes \frac{s}{n}=(na_1, ...,na_k,nb_1,...,nb_r)\otimes \frac{s}{n}=(0,...,0,nb_1,...,nb_r)\otimes\frac{s}{n}=n(0,...,0,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes\frac{s}{n}=(0,...,0,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes n\frac{s}{n}=(0,...,0,b_1,...,b_r)\otimes s$

so the generators of $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ are the same with $G_2\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$. hence my conclusion is $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Z}^r\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$.

is this correct answer? actually I didn't get what is the meaning of "compute $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$" exactly. can we go further from here? or this is it?

Comment: Yes, and $\Bbb Z^r\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\cong\Bbb Q^r$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you tell the detail?

Comment: maybe $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)\otimes 1\mapsto(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ is the correspondence of generators? is this right?

Comment: or $(0,...,0,a,0,...,0)\otimes 1/b\mapsto(0,...,0,a/b,0,...,0)$?

Comment: Since $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ module, we have that $\;\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\cong \Bbb Q\;$ . Rinse and repeat $\;r\;$ times...You may also want to read in the web about "extension of scalars"

Comment: @DonAntonio let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $q=a/b\in\mathbb{Q}$. then $n\otimes q$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$. and $n\otimes q=n\otimes a/b=(nb/b)\otimes a/b=n/b \otimes a=na/b\otimes 1=nq\otimes 1$ thus every general element of $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ can be represented by $\sum n_i\otimes q_i=\sum n_i q_i\otimes 1=(\sum n_i q_i)\otimes 1$ hence $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}=\{q\otimes 1|q\in\mathbb{Q}\}\cong \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user159234 Yes, that looks pretty compact and messy...but correct.

Comment: in $\mathbb{Z}^r\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$, I got $(n_1,...,n_r)\otimes q=(n_1,...,n_r)q\otimes 1$, so the general element is $\sum (n_1^i,...,n_r^i)\otimes q_i=(\sum (n_1^i,...,n_r^i)q_i) \otimes 1$. clearly $\sum (n_1^i,...,n_r^i)q_i$ are in $\mathbb{Q}^r$, and every element in $\mathbb{Q}^r$ can be written in the form of $\sum (n_1^i,...,n_r^i)q_i$, you're right. actually I was writing this comment to ask something but I guess it's solved. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensor product commutes with direct sums:
$$
\biggl(\,\bigoplus_{k=1}^n G_k\biggr)\otimes_A K
\cong
\bigoplus_{k=1}^n (G_k\otimes_A K)
$$
where the $G_k$ are (right) $A$-modules and $K$ is a (left) $A$-module.

So in your case,
$$\def\tens{\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}}
G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}
\cong
(\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{t_1}}\tens)\oplus
\dots\oplus(\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{t_k}}\tens)\oplus(\mathbb{Z}\tens)^r
$$
If $H$ is a finite abelian group, then $H\tens=0$.

The commutation can be proved in the special case of two summands, and then by induction.